# I'm trying to create a new firebase user, and upload the user data to firebase database, but when I try yo get the uid it's always null

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the user uid after creating an account, so I can create a document on Firestore with the uid as document id. The problem is that I get only null, everything is working fine and I'm able to sign the user and receive the code but the uid is always null.

I know I'm accessing the uid before it's initialized because it takes time to restore the authentication state when the app starts so any idea how to wait for it until it's initialized?

First of all, if the data entered is correct then we call `login()` function, then we send the verification code, when the code is sent inside the `onCodeSent()`, the method we call `uploadSelectedImageToFirebaseStorage()` to upload the user image then we call `saveUserToDatabase()` function, and here is the problem. Inside the `saveUserToDatabase()` function, the UID is always null no matter what I tried, am I missing something?

```
@file:Suppress("DEPRECATION")

class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignUpBinding
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var callbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
lateinit var storedVerificationId: String
lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val flProfilePicture = binding.frameProfilePicture
    val tilUserName = binding.tilUserName
    val tilPhoneNumber = binding.tilPhoneNumber
    val startButton = binding.startButton
    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    if (currentUser != null) {
        val intent = Intent(this@SignUpActivity, MainChatsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {  }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {  }

        override fun onCodeSent(
            verificationId: String,
            token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken,
        ) {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Code Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            storedVerificationId = verificationId
            resendToken = token
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, AuthenticatePhoneActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("storedVerificationId", storedVerificationId)
            
            uploadSelectedImageToFirebaseStorage()

            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }

    flProfilePicture.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
    }

    startButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(tilUserName.text.toString())) {
            tilUserName.error = "Enter valid Name"
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(tilPhoneNumber.text.toString())) {
            tilPhoneNumber.error = "Enter valid phone number"
        } else {
            val userName: String = tilUserName.text.toString()
            val userPhoneNumber: String = tilPhoneNumber.text.toString()

            login()
        }
    }
}

private var selectedProfilePicture: Uri? = null

@Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == 0 && data != null) {

        selectedProfilePicture = data.data

        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedProfilePicture)
        val flProfilePicture = binding.frameProfilePicture
        val selectedCircleFrame = binding.selectedPictureCircleFrame

        selectedCircleFrame.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        flProfilePicture.alpha = 0f

    }
}

private fun login() {
    val mobileNumber = binding.tilPhoneNumber
    val number = mobileNumber.text.toString().trim()

    if (number.isNotEmpty()) {
        sendVerificationCode(number)
    } else {
        mobileNumber.error = "Enter a valid phone number"
    }
}

private fun sendVerificationCode(number: String) {

    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
        .setPhoneNumber(number)
        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setActivity(this)
        .setCallbacks(callbacks)
        .build()
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
}

private fun uploadSelectedImageToFirebaseStorage() {
    if (selectedProfilePicture == null) {
        return
    }
    val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$fileName")

    ref.putFile(selectedProfilePicture!!)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                it.toString()
                Log.d("SignUpActivity", "image uploaded successfully")

                saveUserToDatabase(it.toString())
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            saveUserToDatabase(it.toString())
        }
}

private fun saveUserToDatabase(profileImageUrl: String) {
    val tilUserName = binding.tilUserName.text.toString()
    val tilPhoneNumber = binding.tilPhoneNumber.text.toString()
    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid.toString()
    val database = Firebase.database("https://blend-4a9e4-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app")
    val myRef = database.getReference("/users/$uid")
    val user = User(uid, tilPhoneNumber, tilUserName, profileImageUrl)

    Log.d("currentUser", uid)

    myRef.setValue(user)
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Something went wrong, try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
}
```

Comment: At which particular line of code is the UID null?

Comment: in the method `saveUserToDatabase()`, I'm logging the uid and it's null, I know I'm accessing the uid before it's initialized because it takes time to restore the authentication state when the app starts

Comment: Have you tried to use `val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.uid` instead of `val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid.toString()`? Does it work that way?

Comment: no, as I said, I'm accessing the uid before it's initialized